# Android app - RSS

Tags: android, rss

I am a beginner android programmer and I have been creating easy apps using sample code from various sites.  I now want to create an app that would read the weekly ad (just one category from a the list) of any store. Lets assume it is a grocery store...say publix.

I want to display the "beverages" items on sale inside the weekly ad.

How do I go about creating this app? I feel I can achieve this by reading the RSS but how do I get hold of the RSS for any site? Appreciate any guidance or point me to any similar thread that was already discussed here.

Comment: It's difficult to see what you want to do. Please ask a more precise question, asking for "how do I build this app" isn't likely to get any answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a RSS depending on you have the rss feed or not.

Assuming you have the RSS:
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253788/simple-rss-parser-for-android) is a thread about RSS. I recomend you using [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-androidrss/) example about a reader. Its a bit old but editing it a bit it het to work. See the above thread were a commented about that reader example.